# Thymeleaf Expression [#temporals.format( ${event.eventStart} , 'pattern')] @20: EL1043E: Unexpected token. Expected 'rparen())' but was 'lcurly({)'

Tags: spring, format, thymeleaf, expression, offsetdatetime

`event.eventStart` is an OffsetDateTime object.

Added to POM

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-java8time</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Added Java8TimeDialect to TemplateEngine

```
 final SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.addDialect(new Java8TimeDialect());
```

Expected -  This Row Shows Formatted Time in my Email.

```
<span th:text="${#temporals.format( ${event.eventStart} , 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ')}"></span>
```

Actual  -

**`Expression [#temporals.format( ${event.eventStart} , 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ')] @20: EL1043E: Unexpected token. Expected 'rparen())' but was 'lcurly({)'`**

Comment: PS: Had a trouble in the other side. My event.eventStart - is actually String. Thnx

Answer (score 3):

You can't nest `${...}` expressions.  Just remove the extra one you have in the middle.  For example:

```
th:text="${#temporals.format(event.eventStart, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ')}"
```

Comment: And if you really need to evaluate something inside, like a dynamic expression, you can use `__${...}__`